# Unable to cast from string to generic list in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written a code to store uploaded image names into the session list.
A user can upload only 4 images, so there will be max 4 image names in a session.

A user can upload 1, 2, 3 or 4 images based on requirement. If a user selects only 2 images, the session will have only 2, so the rest 2 will throw index out of bound exception!

to handle such situation i have written following code.

```
string image1 = "";
string image2 = "";
string image3 = "";
string image4 = "";
var imageSessList = (List<string>)Session["Images"];
if (imageSessList != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < imageSessList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (imageSessList[i] != null && i == 0)
        {
            image1 = imageSessList[i];
        }
        if (imageSessList[i] != null && i == 1)
        {
            image2 = imageSessList[i];
        }
        if (imageSessList[i] != null && i == 2)
        {
            image3 = imageSessList[i];
        }
        if (imageSessList[i] != null && i == 3)
        {
            image4 = imageSessList[i];
        }
    }
}
```

But now it's showing following error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List"

How can I resolve it, or is there any way to complete this functionality.

Comment: It sounds like `Session["Images"]` contains *one* `string` as a direct `string` reference - not a list.

Comment: Can you please share your code how you assign a vaule to `Session["Images"]`

Comment: @StephanBauer
i have written following lines in foreach:

lstImageNames.Add(destFileName);
                            context.Session["Images"] = lstImageNames;

Comment: If `Session["Images"]` is of type `string` then you need to create a new `List<string>` and then add it to the new list.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Session["Images"]` doesn't contain a list but a string. You have to correct this on the setting side.

A general solution to prevent such errors is by wrapping the session state into a class, and using the typed properties from that class for getting and setting:

```
public static class SessionState
{
    public List<string> Images
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["Images"] as List<string>;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Images"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can just get and set `SessionState.Images`.

Comment: (List<string>)Session["Images"]; is a list of session, i am able to see it too

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: List<string>)Session["Images"]; this line contains list of session.

Comment: No, `Session["Images"]` contains a string as per your error message. Find all occurrences of `Session["Images"]` and replace it with `SessionState.Images`. See where it fails then.

Answer (score 0):

From previously mentioned comments:

> @StephanBauer i have written following lines in foreach: lstImageNames.Add(destFileName); context.Session["Images"] = lstImageNames; – ace 22 mins ago

If `context.Session["Images"] = lstImageNames;` is done in foreach loop, then you are overwriting the value in the session each time.

One more thing i wanted to point out is, string can not only be null but empty too. So, you may want to change your null checks as (just a suggestion):

```
if (!string.IsNulOrEmpty(imageSessList[i])l && i == 0)
```